# Custom jQuery to apply to multiple forms independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a sample jQuery to work in a single form, but now the problem is I will be having multiple forms with similar functions.

So when I something in the first form it applies to the other form, how can I make the forms work independently and use the same jQuery function.

Please see My fiddle to further understand My question
https://jsfiddle.net/sjgrLcqx/17/

jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var childInfoArray = [];

  var formHtml = '<div class="optionBox"><div class="block" style=""><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div><div class="block"><span class="add">Add another child\'s info</span></div></div>';

  var formHtml2 = '<div class="block" style=""><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div>';  

  jQuery('#frmPaymentSantasgrotto').append(formHtml);
  jQuery('#frmPaymentother_Santasgrotto').append(formHtml);


  jQuery('.add').click(function () {
    jQuery('.block:last').before(formHtml2);
    });

    jQuery(".optionBox").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("list" + ++i);
    });

jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block'); 
  jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  childInfoArray.splice( $.inArray(index, childInfoArray), 1 );
  printChildArray() 
});

jQuery('.optionBox').on('keyup', 'input', function () {

  var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block');

  var child = {};

  if (childInfoArray[index] != null) {
    child = childInfoArray[index];
  }
  else {
    child = {
      fullName: '',
      age: '',
      gender: '',
      interest: ''
    }
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('fullName')) {
    child.fullName = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('age')) {
   child.age = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('gender')) {
    child.gender = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('interest')) {
    child.interest = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  childInfoArray[index] = child;
  printChildArray();

});

function printChildArray() {
  var childInfoString = "";
  childInfoArray.forEach(child => {
    Object.values(child).forEach((attribute, index) => {
      childInfoString += attribute;
      if (index !== Object.keys(child).length - 1) {
        childInfoString += ' | ';
      }
      else {
        childInfoString += ' \n';
      }
    });
  });
  $('textarea').html(childInfoString);
  $('#qppquantitySantasgrotto').val(childInfoArray.length);
 }

});
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sjgrLcqx/17/

Answer (score 0):

You should make the forms and their components have unique classes/ids. For example, near the last line of your code where you say

```
$('textarea').html(childInfoString);
```

you are actually targeting both of the textareas so that's why the changes reflect on both forms. You should give each of the forms' textareas their separate classes/ids and reference them that way instead.